# Dynamically setting default value in a dropdown with ColdFusion?

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, coldfusion, cfml

I might be entirely wrong here but is there a way to use `<cfif>` inside of a dropdown to dynamically select the default value of the dropdown?

I'm doing the following:

```
<select class="field select" id="TimeWithXYZYears" name="TimeWithXYZYears" >

<option value="00" <cfif #thisInstance.responses.TimeWithXYZYears# eq 0>selected="selected"</cfif>>0</option>
<option value="01" <cfif #thisInstance.responses.TimeWithXYZYears# eq 1>selected="selected"</cfif>>1</option>
<option value="02" <cfif #thisInstance.responses.TimeWithXYZYears# eq 2>selected="selected"</cfif>>2</option>
<option value="03" <cfif #thisInstance.responses.TimeWithXYZYears# eq 3>selected="selected"</cfif>>3</option>
.
.
.
</select>
```

I'm already getting the value of `TimeWithXYZYears` from a component method invoked earlier in the page, and I tried dumping it on the page and it is giving me the correct values.

Is there any way to do this without writing another function?

Comment: In what way is your code not working just now?  The basic approach you're taking should work.  PS: you don't need the # # inside your IF statements, just do `<cfif thisInstance.responses.TimeWithXYZYears eq 0>`

Comment: Well I removed the ##, but the dropdown is not showing the selected value, on page load. It should be 7 Years and 8 Months for another dropdown with similar <cfif>'s. But it shows 0 0 as the selected value.

Comment: which would imply that thisInstance.responses.TimeWithXYZYears eq 0. Is this the value that you're getting from your 'component method'?  It'd probably help diagnose the problem if you gave us more of your code.

Comment: The value for thisInstance.responses.TimeWithXYZYears is 7.. i dumped it right before the html using cfdump, and it gave the right value. The part of the code where it retrieves the values is another component method with  a select query, and it is retrieving the values correctly.

Comment: If it's appropriate to your situation, using cfselect makes this much simpler.

Comment: @Dan Bracuk: I think cfselect works only in a cfform tag.. nevertheless i tried it as below:                                <span>
<cfselect name="TimeWithXYZYears" id="TimeWithXYZYears" selected="#thisInstance.responses.TimeWithXYZYears#">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="0">1</option>
<option value="0">2</option>
<option value="0">3</option>
<option value="0">4</option>
<option value="0">5</option>
<option value="0">6</option>
<option value="0">7</option>
<option value="0">8</option>
<option value="0">9</option>
</cfselect>
<label>Years</label>
</span>  ... Didn't work   :(

Comment: Is the value for `thisInstance.responses.TimeWithXYZYears` `7` or `07` in your dump?

Comment: @Miguel-F I just tested a comparison of `07` (as a string) and `7` as an integer. They evaluated as being equal. I would probably feel safer throwing a `val` around the TimeWithXYZYears vars though.

Comment: @phantom42 thanks for testing. The code seems like it should be working as written (although the `#` are not needed). I think we are missing some information from the OP...

Comment: @phantom42, you don't need evaluate to compare 7 to 07.  You can use compare().  user2310964, your assumption is correct.  cfselect must be used in conjunction with cfform.  Hence the note about it being appropriate for your situation.  Are you really hard coding your option tags?

Comment: @DanBracuk compare("07",7) evaluates as -1.

Comment: @phantom42, that's correct.  It mean's they are different.  We may be on different wavelengths, but for me, that's the point.

Comment: @user2310964 - As others have said, we cannot reproduce the problem from the snippets you have posted. You need to put together a small, *self-contained*, repro case that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @Leigh:  
I tried running the original code in IE instead of Chrome, and it works just fine. is there any way to make this run in Chrome as well. P.S: I have the latest jquery.BlockUI.js in my javascript library

Comment: @user2310964 - Well the problem is with something in your environment that *we* cannot see from here ;-) So unless you posted some additional code, I can only repeat what I said before: "You need to put together a small, self-contained, repro case that demonstrates the issue".

Answer (score -3):

```
  <select class="field select" id="TimeWithXYZYears" name="TimeWithXYZYears" >

   <option value="00" <cfif thisInstance.responses.TimeWithXYZYears eq "00">selected</cfif>>0</option>
   <option value="01" <cfif thisInstance.responses.TimeWithXYZYears eq "01">selected</cfif>>1</option>
   <option value="02" <cfif thisInstance.responses.TimeWithXYZYears eq "02">selected</cfif>>2</option>
   <option value="03" <cfif thisInstance.responses.TimeWithXYZYears eq "03">selected</cfif>>3</option>
   .
   .
   .
   </select>
```

The only time you need ## is when your varible is being outputed or in quotes. Quotes mean it's not a variable and no quotes means it's a variable. This goes for most CFML tags. Also, SELECTED for HTML is just SELECTED in many cases. The reason why it's not working properly is because your value is not exact with your IF statement. See above for correct usage.

Comment: Also, if I were you I would loop your options so it would be easier to deal with.

Comment: CF requires the #'s when the variable is being rendered to the browser. It has nothing to do with whether or not it's in quotes. As we discussed in the comments above, `00` as a string evaluates as equal to `0` as an integer, so there's no problem with that comparison.

Comment: *The reason why it's not working properly is because your value is not exact with your IF statement* No. The leading zeroes will be ignored because CF [implicitly converts `"00","01",...` to numbers](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09af4-7fc3.html) and performs a **numeric** comparison. (Whether that is the desired result is a different question ..) If you want to consider the leading zeroes, you must perform a [string comparison](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f84.html).